# How to resolve duplicate lang item error?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I couldn't compile ink_env when doing `cargo contract build`. Tried `cargo update` by referencing this other [post] ([error: duplicate lang item in crate `std` (which `arrayvec` depends on): `panic_impl`](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/967/error-duplicate-lang-item-in-crate-std-which-arrayvec-depends-on-panic)). But it still doesn't work.

```
error: duplicate lang item in crate `std` (which `num_traits` depends on): `oom`.                                                                                             |                                                                                                                                                                           = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `ink_allocator` (which `ink_env` depends on)                                                                                = note: first definition in `ink_allocator` loaded from /home/christopherfkk/phala-network-fat-contract-use-case/target/ink/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libink_allocator-20507a21218d777e.rmeta                                                                                                                                                 = note: second definition in `std` loaded from /home/christopherfkk/phala-network-fat-contract-use-case/target/ink/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libstd-a0c0252c27199310.rmeta                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              error[E0152]: found duplicate lang item `panic_impl`                                                                                                                          --> /home/christopherfkk/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_env-3.0.0/src/lib.rs:53:1                                                                       |                                                                                                                                                                        53 | fn panic(info: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {                                                                                                                            | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                              |                                                                                                                                                                           = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `num_traits` depends on)                                                                                       = note: first definition in `std` loaded from /home/christopherfkk/phala-network-fat-contract-use-case/target/ink/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libstd-a0c0252c27199310.rmeta                                                                                                                                                                     = note: second definition in the local crate (`ink_env`)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0152`.                                                                                                         error: could not compile `ink_env` due to 2 previous errors
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two primary troubleshooting steps based off comments and messages surrounding the problem.

- Ensure all your dependencies are set to the *same* branch and tag, mismatches are known to be a cause of this problem ([source](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/269#issuecomment-988763697))
- It is possible that `std` is leaking into your runtime code when it shouldn't. If your runtime relies on a crate, it should be `no-std` capable.

  One possible culprit can be `serde`, a dependency that *does* have `no-std` support but can have `std` enabled by default, triggering the problem. ([source](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/2971#issuecomment-506954545)).

  **This was the cause of the problem in my case and applying the patch in the comment resolved it**

It might be a good idea to go through all your dependencies and ensure that

- they support `no-std` environments and
- `std` is not enabled by default (that's what `default-features = false` accomplishes) but also that `[package]/std` is added to the `std` feature within `Cargo.toml`

Answer (score 4):

If you have a local crate, add this in the lib.rs:

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
```

If you use remote crates, add `default-features = false,` in your Cargo.toml. For example:

```
imported_crate = { git = "...", default-features = false, branch = "..." }
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically this is an issue with versioning - you *must* have the same versions from Substrate upstream in your Cargo.toml and Cargo.lock file.

Try `cargo tree` to investigate the root cause if unclear from the errors you are seeing. Typically resolved by [an update](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-update.html#examples) `cargo update -p <some substrate crate>`

Another common cause, that might be applicable here specifically, is "leaking" `std` in a no-std environment, like a Substrate runtime. In the context of `ink` this is also critical, as it compiles to Wasm where [you likely cannot use `std`](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/reference/which-crates-work-with-wasm.html?highlight=no_std#no_std)

Answer (score 3):

You need to import `num_traits` with `default-features = false` in your Cargo.toml file. This will solve the problem. The problem here being that ink itself declares the `oom` handler, but you also import `std` through `num_traits`. `std` will then also provide the `oom` handler, which is not allowed and leading to your problem.

Comment: Tried this `num-traits = { version = "0.2", default-features = false }`  but still threw the same error.

Comment: Maybe you are having some other dependency that pulls in std.