# build error because found duplicate lang item `panic_impl`

Tags: crates

[image]

I added following in the beginning of lib.rs

> #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

Here is dependency

```rust
[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.6.1", default-features = false, features = [
    "derive",
] }
scale-info = { version = "2.5.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, optional = true, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-session = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-transaction-payment = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-runtime = { version = "24.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-staking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
rstd = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", package = "sp-std", default-features = false, branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
log = { default-features = false, version = '0.4.14' }
serde = {version="1.0.136", feature= ["derive"]}

[dev-dependencies]
sp-core = { version = "21.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-io = { version = "23.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git",  default-features = false,  branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-runtime = { version = "24.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

[features]
std = [
    "codec/std",
    "frame-benchmarking?/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "rstd/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "pallet-session/std",
]
```

Also I tried with `default-features = false` for serde, but It caused more problems

Comment: Maybe try changing to serde `1.0.85` as that seems to be [what the polkadot-v1.0.0 branch is on](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/948fbd2fd1233dc26dbb9f9bbc1d2cca2c03945d/client/cli/Cargo.toml#L29C1-L29C22)

Comment: Can you share the link to your code?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier hi [link](https://github.com/nhathuyenqt/debugging). I only add serde = { version = "1.0.119" } in cargo.tolm of pallet template.

Comment: This question has been asked countless of times, please use the search and theck the other Qs. Eg: [duplicate lang item in crate \`std\` (which \`my\_crate\` depends on): \`panic\_impl\`](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3432/duplicate-lang-item-in-crate-std-which-my-crate-depends-on-panic-impl)

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi Yes, I did before posting this question. But those answers didn't work with my case.

Answer (score 2):

Disable its default features:

```
serde = { version = "1.0.119", default-features = false }
```

And add it to the std part:

```
std = [
    "serde/std",
    ..
]
```

Then everything works well in my local.

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.51s

xavier in debugging at  main <!> via  v1.76.0-nightly takes 700ms
Sat Dec 16 01:17:30 2023 - 54%
λ
```