# duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on): `panic_impl`

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, tutorials

I am following the Substrate tutorial on [adding pallets](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/add-a-pallet/). However, when I add `pallet-nicks` to the `Cargo.toml` located in the `runtime` folder and then add the `pallets-nicks` implementation to the `lib.rs` file in `runtime/src`, I get the following error:

```
error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /code/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-28bcc0f1aaf2e4a2.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /code/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-151d2b924b052e86.rmeta
```

This is my `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[package]
name = "node-template-runtime"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
description = "A fresh FRAME-based Substrate node, ready for hacking."
authors = ["Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>"]
homepage = "https://substrate.io/"
edition = "2021"
license = "Unlicense"
publish = false
repository = "https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.1.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }

pallet-aura = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-balances = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-grandpa = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-randomness-collective-flip = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-sudo = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
frame-try-runtime = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-timestamp = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-transaction-payment = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
frame-executive = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-block-builder = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-consensus-aura = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-core = { version = "7.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-inherents = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-offchain = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-runtime = { version = "7.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-session = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-std = { version = "5.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-transaction-pool = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
sp-version = { version = "5.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
Added this line -> pallet-nicks = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }

# Used for the node template's RPCs
frame-system-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }

# Used for runtime benchmarking
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
frame-system-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }

# Local Dependencies
pallet-template = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../pallets/template" }

[build-dependencies]
substrate-wasm-builder = { version = "5.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "frame-try-runtime?/std",
    "frame-system-benchmarking?/std",
    "frame-benchmarking?/std",
    "codec/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "frame-executive/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system-rpc-runtime-api/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "frame-try-runtime/std",
    "pallet-aura/std",
    "pallet-balances/std",
    "pallet-grandpa/std",
    "pallet-randomness-collective-flip/std",
    "pallet-sudo/std",
    "pallet-template/std",
    "pallet-timestamp/std",
    "pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api/std",
    "pallet-transaction-payment/std",
    "sp-api/std",
    "sp-block-builder/std",
    "sp-consensus-aura/std",
    "sp-core/std",
    "sp-inherents/std",
    "sp-offchain/std",
    "sp-runtime/std",
    "sp-session/std",
    "sp-std/std",
    "sp-transaction-pool/std",
    "sp-version/std",
    Added this line -> "pallet-nicks/std",
]
runtime-benchmarks = [
    "frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-support/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-system-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-system/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-balances/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-grandpa/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-template/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-timestamp/runtime-benchmarks",
    "sp-runtime/runtime-benchmarks",
]
try-runtime = [
    "frame-try-runtime/try-runtime",
    "frame-executive/try-runtime",
    "frame-system/try-runtime",
    "frame-support/try-runtime",
    "pallet-aura/try-runtime",
    "pallet-balances/try-runtime",
    "pallet-grandpa/try-runtime",
    "pallet-randomness-collective-flip/try-runtime",
    "pallet-sudo/try-runtime",
    "pallet-template/try-runtime",
    "pallet-timestamp/try-runtime",
    "pallet-transaction-payment/try-runtime",
]
```

This is the implementation that I added to the `lib.rs` file in `runtime/src/`:

```rust
impl pallet_nicks::Config for Runtime {
  // The Balances pallet implements the ReservableCurrency trait.
  // `Balances` is defined in `construct_runtime!` macro.
  type Currency = Balances;
  // Set ReservationFee to a value.
  type ReservationFee = ConstU128<100>;
  // No action is taken when deposits are forfeited.
  type Slashed = ();
  // Configure the FRAME System Root origin as the Nick pallet admin.
  // https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_system/enum.RawOrigin.html#variant.Root
  type ForceOrigin = frame_system::EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
  // Set MinLength of nick name to a desired value.
  type MinLength = ConstU32<8>;
  // Set MaxLength of nick name to a desired value.
  type MaxLength = ConstU32<32>;
  // The ubiquitous event type.
  type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
}

// Also added the pallet to the construct_runtime macro:
construct_runtime!(
    pub struct Runtime
    where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system,
        RandomnessCollectiveFlip: pallet_randomness_collective_flip,
        Timestamp: pallet_timestamp,
        Aura: pallet_aura,
        Grandpa: pallet_grandpa,
        Balances: pallet_balances,
    Nicks: pallet_nicks,
        TransactionPayment: pallet_transaction_payment,
        Sudo: pallet_sudo,
        // Include the custom logic from the pallet-template in the runtime.
        TemplateModule: pallet_template,
    }
);
```

If I comment out the implementation from the `lib.rs` and the `construct_runtime` macro, I can build successfully. I am very new to Rust and Substrate. Any ideas on how I can go about fixing this? I've seen questions with similar errors but I've been unable to resolve this error.

This is the result of running `rustup show`. I am running all of this on WSL on Windows:

```
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /root/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.65.0 (897e37553 2022-11-02)
```

Comment: This error is just when you add the nicks pallet? or without the nick pallet you have it too

Comment: Only upon adding the nicks pallet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve duplicate lang item error?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/how-to-resolve-duplicate-lang-item-error)

Comment: I have tried the suggestions solutions but could not resolve the error. In my case, the error goes away if I comment out the code related to the nicks pallet from the lib.rs file.

Comment: I was able to resolve this error by using version: polkadot-v0.9.31 instead of polkadot-v0.9.35

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the substrate-node-template, I have seen this PR that fixes it: *[remove space from manifest key branch in all the cargo.toml files](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/pull/407)*

In the meantime is approved if you want to try it locally just replace in all files (Cargo.toml files) `" branch"` with `"branch"` (removing the space)