# duplicate lang item in crate `core`

Tags: ink, smart-contract

Unable to build ink! smart contract

**My command:**

`cargo contract build --release`

**Issue**:

attempted to define built-in macro more than once

/Users/xxx/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/macros/mod.rs:1423:5
|
1423 |     macro_rules! cfg {
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|

note: previously defined here
--> /Users/xxx/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/macros/mod.rs:1423:5
|
1423 |     macro_rules! cfg {
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

...

duplicate lang item in crate `core`

**My Rust version:**

`installed targets for active toolchain`

aarch64-apple-darwin

wasm32-unknown-unknown

`active toolchain`

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)

rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)

**`cargo-contract` version:**

cargo-contract-contract 3.2.0-unknown-aarch64-apple-darwin

Comment: Check this answer:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/how-to-resolve-duplicate-lang-item-error

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved

Because Rust version is incompatible with `ink!` version and `open-brush` version

It should be:

- rustc - 1.72
- ink! - 4.2.0
- open-brush - 4.0.0-beta